# insert method of binary tree

Tags: data-structures

what's the difference in
[ insert_node(&(tmp->left),value);] VS [ tmp=tmp->right; insert_node(&(tmp),value);]

```
void insert_node(struct btree **bt,int value)
{
     btree *tmp= *bt, *r ;

     if(*bt==NULL)// first node 
     {
          (*bt)=(struct btree *)malloc(sizeof(btree));
          (*bt)->data=value;
          (*bt)->left=NULL;
          (*bt)->right=NULL;           
     }       
     else
     {
         if(value > tmp->data)
            insert_node(&(tmp->right),value);   
         else
            insert_node(&(tmp->left),value);                 
     }

      #if 0  //start
           OR  /** COMMENT START

         earlier I had below piece of code but not working 
         can any please explain what's the difference in  
         insert_node(&(tmp->left),value); VS [ tmp=tmp->right; insert_node(&(tmp),value);]
         COMMENT END **/ 

      else
     {
         if(value > tmp->data)
            tmp=tmp->right;  
         else
            tmp=tmp->left ;
            insert_node(&tmp,value);                 
     }
   #endif //end

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the non-working case, you are giving it the address of your `tmp` variable, and therefore updating that pointer, which is on your stack and not going to be used for anything.

In the working case, you are giving the address of the actual pointer in your bt node which is what you want.

Comment: hi Francis but before calling I am initializing my tmp by proper value tmp=tmp->left , tmp->right then I am passing by address . can you please explain more

Comment: Yes, tmp is pointing to whatever tmp->right was pointing to, but you are modifying the pointer in tmp (as you are giving the address of tmp), and what you want to modify is the pointer in tmp->right (in the working example you give the address of that).

Answer (score 0):

There is no semantic difference. #2 is storing the next node in a local variable, which will be a register, whereas #1 is storing the node into the register, but it won't be available as a local variable.

If you need to access the value again, use #2.

Comment: No idea what you explained can please elaborate